# Upload, Retrieve PDF and DOC file to server using Jquery, Web Api, Sql Server(store in binary format)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Using jquery, Web Api and sql server I need to upload the pdf or doc file to server and store  in Sql Server in Binary format and also retrieve the files and download to the client system.

Answer (score 0):

I put a quick example of it here. It requires a cleanup but should give you a good idea:
https://gist.github.com/seattlekiran/7713416